# __attribute__((io)), __attribute__((address)) in gcc for AVR don't seem to have any effect

Tags: gcc, avr, avr-gcc

I am trying to use variable attributes specifically provided by AVR flavor of gcc (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/AVR-Variable-Attributes.html#AVR-Variable-Attributes).

The manual says that these special attributes should allow me to force the placement of a variable at the predetermined memory address. They even give an example:

```
volatile int porta __attribute__((address (0x600)));
```

But when I compile and debug this code example from the above mentioned document, the variable declared with such attribute is placed into a location in SRAM that compiler and linker determine, not at the address 0x600, as requested. Actually, if I remove the attribute entirely from the declaration, the end result does not change - the variable is placed at the same "whatever" address. Same thing happens when I use "io" and "io_low" attributes instead of "address".

I am using gcc toolchain packaged in the latest version Atmel Studio 7.0.19.31 targeted at 8-bit MCUs (ATMega64).

Hence the question: has anyone tried to use these special AVR-specific attributes with any success?

Important notes:

1. I am aware that in general to accomplish a placement of a variable at a fixed address in gcc you need to follow a two-step process (using section attribute and then modifying the linker script), but specificially for AVR it seems like these single-step attributes were provided, the question is how to make them work. A two-step process is not an option for me.
2. I am aware that in general one can always do this:
   `*(volatile int*)0x600 = your_data_here;`
   But this is not an option for me either, I need an actual variable declared (because I want to map it onto a bitwise structure to have access to individual bits without explicitly using the masks and logical operations.

So I am really looking for a way to make the provided attributes work, not for a workaround. What am I missing?

Comment: these things are not workarounds they are the things that work.  trying to get bitfields to work or pragmas and other directives, those are workarounds and lead to a life of maintenance of the code. If job security is the goal then continue otherwise use the solutions that just work.

Comment: What is the toolchain doing if anything with your attributes?

Comment: this appears to be a bug...but...are you using the linker scripts that come with the toolchain or using your own?

Comment: Using out-of-the box linker scripts without any changes.

Comment: I am a fan of standard approaches too, but in IAR EWB I had PORTA_Bit4 as a separate variable (thanks to mapping of a bit-wise structure onto a fixed address) and that was making the code more readable: PORTA_Bit4 = 0;. Reading was done via the same assignment operator: foo = PORTA_Bit4; I am trying to migrate to avr-gcc and keep the same readability. Sadly, the standard solution of typecasting via the pointer and using bitmasks and logical operators only allows to create a macro for reading, writing via assignment operator is not possible, you have to resort to a macro with parameters.

Comment: You could probably use the code in note #2 but replace `int` with a structure you define that has bitfields.  Still, it's valid to ask how to get these particular GCC attributes to work.

Answer (score -1):

```
typedef struct {
  uint8_t rx:4;
  uint8_t tx:4;
} Pio_TXRXMUX_t;
#define Pio_TXRXMUX (*(volatile Pio_TXRXMUX_t *)(0x22)) //PORTA on ATMEGA1280
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.